# How to block an html link without changing href?

Tags: javascript, html

Say I have a link:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">Example!</a>
```

I want to keep the link intact, but I'd like an onclick event to decide if the link is clickable or not

```
<a onclick='stopLight()' href="http://www.example.com">Example!</a>

function stopLight() {

    // conditional logic
    // return true or return false
}
```

so if stopLight() == true, then link works, if stopLight() == false, then link doesn't.
Is making this possible without changing the href, because I'd rather not

Comment: `onclick='return stopLight()'` is the correct syntax

Comment: Are you using jQuery/some framework or raw JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `return stopLight()` for the `onclick` handler.
<sub>As mplungjan suggested in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13882167/how-to-block-an-html-link-without-changing-href/13882256#comment19121591_13882167)</sub>

Comment: Yes, as I suggested in my comment

Comment: ahhh, return stopLight, yaaaaay u guys are smart!

Answer (score 2):

In order to cut the default action:

```
stopLight = function (e) {
    window.event.preventDefault();
}​
```

This will prevent the event from happening.

So you could do:

```
<a onclick='isStopLight()' href="http://www.example.com">Example!</a>
```

And in the JS

```
isStopLight= function(){
   if(stopLight()){
      window.event.preventDefault();
   } 
}

stopLight = function () {
    // conditional logic
    // return true or return false
}​
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with jQuery, and the event.preventDefault() method:

```
$('a.yourLink').on('click',function(e){
  if (stopLight()){ 
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

if stopLight is true the default behavior of `<a>` will be prevented, else it executes normal

Comment: Corrected it. I'm sorry for that mistake

Answer (score 1):

Plain JS

- inline

```
<a onclick='return stopLight()' href="http://www.example.com">Example!</a>
```

- unobtrusive:

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("stoplight").onclick=function() {
    // conditional logic
    // return true or return false
  }
}

<a id="stoplight" href="http://www.example.com">Example!</a>
```

jQuery

```
<a id="stoplight" href="http://www.example.com">Example!</a>

$(function() {
  $("#stoplight").on("click",function(e) {
    // conditional logic
    if (false condition) e.preventDefault(); // (or return false;) 
  });
});
```